# What is the average Ni-Fe crystal length in iron meteorites?

Tags: asteroids, meteor, meteorite, meteoroid

Iron-core meteorites display an awesome criss-cross pattern known as the Widmanstätten pattern, shown below:

[image: Cross-section of an iron-core meteorite]
(photo by Dr. Patrick M. Len, taken from [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Widmanstatten_hand.jpg))

I TA for an intro-level astronomy/planetary science class, and today we discussed meteorites. A student asked me what the average length of these crystals is for iron meteorites, but I hesitated. The samples we had available (and the image above) made it look like the average length was on the order of a centimeter, but with great variation. I'm curious as to whether there is a more quantitative answer.

#### My question:

How long is the average length of a given linear crystal in a typical iron meteorite? How much variation is there from sample to sample?